# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve vue-editor-js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, mixins, editorjs

I am using VUE JS in Laravel and want to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-editor-js) package of block editor, I have added import statement `import Editor from 'vue-editor-js'` but after running `npm run dev` command it shows error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-editor-js'`, also the package is there in node_module folder. Please help me out.

Please also suggest if there is any other block editor plugin in VUE JS, should be more similar like WordPress Gutenberg.

Comment: update  laravel mix to ^6.0

Answer (score 4):

```
import Editor from 'vue-editor-js/src/index'
```

try this way ...Maybe it's work and version 2.0.2